# After Angularjs validation is true do a normal form submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am implementing AngularJS on an existing web application that requires a common HTTP POST like you would do without AngularJS.

Does any one have a work around to do that?
i have tried setting action="#" and action="." and just action and then do some jquery to inject a action like this. but nothing works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").get(0).setAttribute( "action", "test.html" );
</script>
```

HERE IS MY FORM AND CODE
    //MY FORM

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" xt-form novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.fornavn.$invalid && !userForm.fornavn.$pristine }">
                                <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Fornavn <span class="star-color">*</span></label>
                                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('fornavn'); ?>" name="fornavn" ng-model="userFormData.fornavn" class="form-control" xt-validate msg-required="Du skal udfylde dit Fornavn" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.efternavn.$invalid && !userForm.efternavn.$pristine }">
                                <label class=" control-label" for="textinput">Efternavn <span class="star-color">*</span></label>
                                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('efternavn'); ?>" name="efternavn" ng-model="userFormData.efternavn" class="form-control" xt-validate msg-required="Du skal udfylde dit Efternavn" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

            <button  id="membership-box__payBtn" type="submit" ng-model="userFormData.betaling" name="betaling" class="btn btn-success text-uppercase">Gå til betaling</button>


</form>



//CODEIGNITER CONTROLLER

if (isset($_POST['betaling'])) {


$data['tilBetaling'] = array(
'oprettelse'        => $this->input->post('oprettelse'),
//                'medlemskab'        => $this->input->post('medlemskab'),
'tilBetaling'       => str_replace(',', '.', $this->input->post('tilBetaling')),
'pr_maaned'         => $this->input->post('pr_maaned'),
'start_date'        => $this->input->post('start_date'),
'til_dato'          => $this->input->post('til_dato'),
'pakke'             => $this->input->post('pakke'),
'type'              => $this->input->post('medlemskabTypeFinal'),
'getCenter'         => $this->input->post('getCenter'),
'medlemskabPakkePID'=> $this->input->post('medlemskabPakkePID'),
'ekstraInput'       => $this->input->post('ekstraInput'),
'periode_price'     => $this->input->post('periode_price'),
'kampagneTag'       => $this->input->post('kampagneTag'),
//                'header'            => $this->input->post('header'),
);



//Gem array til session
$_SESSION['betaling'] = $data['tilBetaling'];

}
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of using Angular in the first place. It's for building async web app where you call to some backend service for data. All "reloading" should be handled by angular itself, not by "physically" reloading the page.

Comment: I know, but as i wrote "am implementing AngularJS on an existing web application that requires a common HTTP POST like you would do without AngularJS."

Comment: I know what you wrote but you will get yourself a lot of trouble if you will be trying to "eat soup with a fork". Just a friendly warning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you do an AngularJs submit, the request does not go to server. The control still remains on client side. Then you can post the data/form etc through `$http` service. You can inject $http service in your controller. as

```
app.controller('reviewCtrl', ['$http', function($http){
        $scope.addReview = function(product){
        //use $http service here
        // Simple POST request example (passing data) :
        $http.post(' / someUrl ', {msg:' hello word!'}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
          });
        }
        }]);
```

*note*: please review the syntax before running the code.

Comment: This is quite misleading having this as the correct answer, since this is definitely NOT a correct answer. This code is about an Angular XHR post request not a normal form submit as asked.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a normal submit, you can handle ngClick in your controller:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form name="userForm" action="user/add" method="post">
         Name: <input name="name" ng-model="user.name" />
         ...
         <button ng-click="onSubmit(userForm)">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.onSubmit = function(form) {
       if (form.$valid) {
           var e = document.getElementsByName(form.$name);
           e[0].submit();
       }
   }
});
```

### An Alternative Solution

As an alternative, consider leveraging services, and redirecting after a successful POST in AngularJS.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="onSubmit(user)">
         Name: <input name="name" ng-model="user.name" />
         ...
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.factory('UserService', function($http) {
     return {
        addUser: function(user) {
           return $http({method:'POST', url:'api/user/add', data: user });
        }
     }
});
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $location, UserService) {
   $scope.onSubmit = function(user) {
       if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
            UserService.addUser(user).success(function() {                    
                $location.path('/user/addSuccessful')
            });
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: hm the JS part doesent seem to work, im getting error on e[0].submit();

Comment: try replacing with `angular.element(e).submit()`

Comment: Sorry, it should be 'getElementsByName' - typo

Answer (score 0):

To submit the Angular Js form ONLY after Angular validations are through or passed, you must use `reviewForm.$valid` flag chack in `ng-submit`.

With this flag check, the form will not get submitted until all validations are passed.

```
<form name="reviewForm" ng-controller="reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewForm.$valid && reviewCtrl.addReview(product)" novalidate>
....
....
</form>
```

Comment: But then i dont get the "normal" form HTTP form submit

Comment: And thats the problem :( i just need to get a normal HTTP post form submit instead of the angularjs form ajax submit